# UberCart product image won't scale

Tags: ubercart

The image in a product (full view not teaser) is coming in full size (and too big) and I can't figure out how to change it.
Looking at the Product content type I see the 'Preview image style' is 'Thumbnail (100x)'. I read in some doc the Preview image style should be 'uc_product' so I'm a bit surprised by that.
In an attempt to figure it out I went to >>Media>>Image styles and changed every image style to Scale 50x50. Images in the teaser responded to the change but on the product page the image is still coming in large (full size probably).
Also as a guess, I went to Configuration>>Media>>Colorbox and change Max width, Max height, Initial width & Initial height to very small values. This made no difference.

Any suggestions for solving this or tips for figuring it out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the css property for the image in the full page was written as width:100% and height:auto , so it will always makes an image in large full size. you can check by inspect element to see the correct path of image style is coming or not.[image: Please see the image below]

You can get the image path from there and paste that in new tab to see what size of image is coming without applying any css rules.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You may be right. When I inspect the item I see the height and width are set to 800. Whereas on the teaser images which are sizing according to the Image styles, there is no such thing happening. I was not able to find the applicable/offending CSS, but then my CSS skill leaves much to be desired. So I'll take this up on a CSS forum. - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to indirectly be a CSS problem.
I could not find a style in the css that controlled the the image size for any images. 
The fix was to go to the Product content type > Manage Display and for the Image field change Format to one of the following:

> Colorbox - which then present you with options to choose styles such as uc_product
>   OR
>   'Ubercart product' - I noticed the teaser was already set to this which explained why the teaser image was sizing but not product detail image.